# Unable to connect to pgsql in Laravel in Docker

Tags: laravel, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, php-pgsql

I am developing a Web application using Laravel. I am an experienced Laravel developer. But, now I am trying to use Docker as my development environment.  But I am so new to Docker. Now I am trying to connect to the Postgres database. I added the Postgres docker image in the docker-composer.yml as well. But when I run migration, I am getting error and it is not connecting to the database.

This is my docker-compose.xml file.

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: docker/web.docker
    volumes:
    - ./:/var/www
    ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "443:443"
    - "9000:9000"
    links:
    - app
  app:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: docker/app.docker
    volumes:
    - ./:/var/www
    links:
    - mysql
    - redis
    - beanstalk
    - cache
    environment:
    - "DB_PORT=3306"
    - "DB_HOST=mysql"
    - "REDIS_PORT=6379"
    - "REDIS_HOST=redis"
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.18
    environment:
    - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret"
    - "MYSQL_DATABASE=docker"
    ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  pgsql:
    image: postgres:10.1
    restart: always
    environment:
    - POSTGRES_DB=docker
    - POSTGRES_USER=root
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret
    ports:
    - 5431:5431
    volumes:
    - ./.docker/conf/postgres/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
  redis:
    image: redis:3.0
    ports:
    - "6379:6379"
  beanstalk:
    image: schickling/beanstalkd
    ports:
    -  "11300:11300"
  cache:
    image: memcached:alpine
    ports:
    - "11211:11211"
```

I know I added the Mysql image as well. When I connect to the Mysql image, it was working. When I connect to the Postgres, I am getting error.

This is my database settings in env file for connecting to the Postgres.

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=pgsql
DB_PORT=5431
DB_DATABASE=docker
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

When I run migration in the terminal like this

```
docker-compose exec app php artisan migrate --seed
```

I got this error.

```
In Connection.php line 647:

  could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = public and table_name = migrations)  




In PDOConnection.php line 50:

  could not find driver  


In PDOConnection.php line 46:

  could not find driver
```

What is wrong with my installation?

Answer (score -1):

You didn't add your docker/app.docker details, but if this is PHP running, you need to make sure both php7-pgsql and php7-pdo are installed on this container. driver is usuallu JUST THAT phpX-mysql or phpX-pgsql. X is the optional version number, depending on which repo you're using for php. i.e with default ubuntu repo php-pgsql will be just fine, but with alpine images you have to use php7-pgsql.
with sury repo, you'll have to use specific version i.e php7.2-pgsql.